# Show that $( \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} )/( \mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that $( \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} )/( \mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

I want to show this isomorphism in the context of rings
How can I build morphism?

Comment: You meant $\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times  \mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{Z} \times n \mathbb{Z}}$. Take a morphism $ \mathbb{Z} \to   (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ and extend it to $\mathbb{Z}\times  \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\times  (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. If you don't like rings, start with the corresponding abelian groups.

Comment: I took the Ker of morphism and applied the first isomorphism theorem, but I could not conclude the result.

Comment: What morphism exactly ? What is its kernel and image ? And do you apply the 1st isomorphism th. ?

Answer (score 2):

To construct an isomorphism $\varphi: A/I\rightarrow B$ is equivalent to find a surjective morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $\ker f=I$. This correspondence between morphisms from $A$ and morphism from $A/I$ is part of the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).

So to prove the desire isomorphism you need to find a morphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\ker f = \mathbb{Z}\times n\mathbb{Z}$. In this case the map $f(a,b)=b \text{ mod } n$ works.

In fact, is easy to see that $f$ is surjective and also we have $(a,b)\in \ker f \iff b \equiv 0 \text{ mod } n \iff b\in n\mathbb{Z}\iff (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times n\mathbb{Z}$.